# How can i put an image at the top center of a container

Tags: html, css

I am new to HTML and CSS. I am trying to center an image at the top center of the container and then add text below it.
I am not sure where i am going wrong here

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}

h1, h2 {
    font-family: 'Amatica SC', cursive;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-align: center;
}

p {
    font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
}

.header {
    background-color: skyblue;
    height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #4f889f;
    padding: 1px;
}

.container div {
    padding: 1%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    min-height: 500px;
}

#container .left-col img {
    min-width: 70px;
    min-height: 70px;
    max-width: 250%;
    max-height: 250%;
    top: -50%;
    left: -50%;
    bottom: -50%;
    right: -50%;
    position: absolute;
}

.left-col, .right-col {
    background-color: #f4f4f4;
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="header">
    <h1>The 3 Column Layout</h1>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="left-col">
        <img src="Cyber.jpg" width="200" height=150"/>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

[I am trying to center this image in the middle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D6f4n.png)
How can I do that?

Comment: Did you try class="img-responsive" ?

Comment: add these two classes to your css code:

.left-col {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.left-col img{
    align-self: center;
}